# image not change on change swatch option

Tags: color-swatches

hi I using this code into magento 2.1.0 vesion but it is not showing swatch option into configurable product.

Please give me suggestion for this.

Comment: which code? It looks like you forgot to paste the actual code. Please update the question with code and explain what you expect it to do and what exactly happens

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom theme then make file (renderer.phtml) in Magento_Swatches\templates\product\view\

```
i.e.: Magento_Swatches\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml

and paste below code (only for magento 2.1.0)



<div class="swatch-opt" data-role="swatch-options"></div>
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"], function ($) {
        var oJsonConfig = <?php echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>;
        $('.swatch-opt').SwatchRenderer({                    
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });
    $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function() {
    // NOTE: Using .one() instead of .on() to prevent duplicate bindings.
    $('.fotorama').one('fotorama:ready', function(e, fotorama, extra) {
      // Update product images faster when clicking on color swatch
      $('.swatch-option.color').click(function() {        
        var sOptionId = this.getAttribute('option-id');
        for (var attributeId in oJsonConfig.attributes) {
          console.log(oJsonConfig);
          var oAttribute = oJsonConfig.attributes[attributeId];
          if (oAttribute.code==='color') {
            for (var i=0; i<oAttribute.options.length; ++i) {
              var oOption = oAttribute.options[i];
              if (oOption.id===sOptionId) {
                // Gather images
                var aImages = oJsonConfig.images[oOption.products[0]],
                  aFotoramaImages = [];
                for (var j=0; j<aImages.length; ++j) {
                  if (aImages[j].isMain) {
                    // Main image (first position)
                    aFotoramaImages[0] = {
                      full: aImages[j].full,
                      img: aImages[j].img,
                      thumb: aImages[j].thumb
                    };
                  } else {
                    // Subsequent images
                    aFotoramaImages[aImages[j].position] = {
                      full: aImages[j].full,
                      img: aImages[j].img,
                      thumb: aImages[j].thumb
                    };
                  }
                }
                // Load images into Fotorama
                // API reference: http://fotorama.io/customize/api/
                fotorama.load(aFotoramaImages);
                break;
              }
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
</script>
```